# Unsure how to hang awning on garage, nor what bolts to use

Tags: mounting, studs, bolts

I bought a light awning set to put on the side of my garage, and it came with the following anchor bolts:

[image: Anchor bolt for awning]

My garage has a wooden panel attached to wooden studs inside the wall and I am trying to figure out the best way to attach to the outside. Here are three potential options:

[image: Awning Choices]

Because of the stud width (16in) and the awning bolt widths (18in), only one set of the three bolt holes will line up on a stud. I like the middle option for that reason, but notice that both holes won't fit. I am happy to build a wooden spacer).

Question 1: Which option for mounting makes the most sense?

Question 2: What bolts should I use if I have to replace the concrete anchor bolts?

Comment: You say the awning bolt holes are spaced 18" but it appears you can space each independent bracket any width you need or do they correspond to a specific place on the awning ?? The middle option with spacer block below is your best bet if you can not get each bracket into a stud. Yes you need to replace the anchors with a beefy wood screw such as a ledger bolt.

Comment: No, unfortunately, the awning itself has the brackets set 18" apart. Ah, "ledger bolt" was the term I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The middle photo will be best with a spacer underneath. Since the top screw is doing the lions share of supporting the awning then the spacer is really just keeping the bracket solid and not holding as much weight but use a screw that will get through the shingles and into the sheathing.

Pre drill pilot holes and insert an outdoor rated caulking into each hole to keep water out.

Use [ledger bolts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000LNVQVS) meant for deck ledger board in place of the anchors.

Make sure the white trim board is fastened into structure/studs.